# Is this use of the word essential correct?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, semantics

Is this a correct use of *essential*:

> According to penguins, in order to save the world, limiting fish intake is thought essential.

Comment: I'd change it to be "thought to be essential", but it's acceptable to omit them.

Comment: Barmar is not the only one who finds "thought essential" somehow slightly awkward (I prefer "considered essential") - but (as Barmar also says) it's correct.  However, am I reading the sentence right?  Are you saying that this is an opinion widespread among penguins?

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, but there are certain nuances to be aware of.

> According to penguins, in order to save the world, limiting fish intake is thought essential.

This means that penguins believe or claim that limiting fish intake is thought (by unspecified people or animals) to be essential in order to save the world.  The penguins could be relaying the opinion of others, which they may or may not share.  The implicit suggestion is that the penguins probably agree with, or don't oppose, the view they're relaying, but this isn't certain and is open to contradiction.  (Perhaps, although this is unlikely, the next sentence is "But the penguins strongly disagree with this consensus".)

> According to penguins, in order to save the world, limiting fish intake is essential.

This means that penguins believe or claim that limiting fish intake is essential in order to save the world.  The penguins are expressing their own view.

Comment: You make a good point. Cheers!